# Getting NullPointer Exception when Switching between Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have 3 Activities

Activity1
Avtivity2
Activity3

Here The Code:

Activity1:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity1.this,Acivity2.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();           
b.putParcelableArrayList("actionArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(0)); 
b.putParcelableArrayList("comedyArray", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) AllListArray.get(1));
intent.putExtras(b);             
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2:

```
//get the Bundle of movie category data data from previous activity
        Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();

        actionArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("actionArray");
        comedyArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("comedyArray");


 public void btnClicker(View v)
    {
        Intent  i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity3.class);;
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
       switch(v.getId())//get the button label id from respective View
       { 
        case R.id.actionBtn:             
            b.putParcelableArrayList("movieCategorie", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) actionArray); 
            b.putString("movieCategorieDisplay","Action Movies");
            i.putExtras(b);   
             startActivity(i);          
             break;

        case R.id.comedyBtn:
            b.putParcelableArrayList("movieCategorie", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) comedyArray); 
              b.putString("movieCategorieDisplay","Comedy Movies");
            i.putExtras(b);   
             startActivity(i);
             break;
```

Activity3:

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Acivity2.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
                CategoryListView.this.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

The Problem is When I click on Backbutton(on the Mobile BackButton) in my Activity3 Some Times Getting NullPionterException

The Exception Points in this line in Activity2

```
actionArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("actionArray");
```

Could any one help me?

Comment: Put that code in try/catch block, problem will be solved.

Comment: @pratik how will it solve the problem?

Comment: It will, because when you switched back, you have received null data in your arrays, which Bundle data you are receiving there. So you can put null validation there or you need to put try/catch block. So app will not crashed and exception will be fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because bundle getting null so check your bundle `null` like@.

```
if(recdData!=null){

actionArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("actionArray");
 comedyArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("comedyArray");
}
```

**Updated**

Even pass appropriate Context while calling Intent as mention by *Biraj Zalavadia*

Used:

> Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this, Acivity2.class);

Instead:

> Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Acivity2.class);

Comment: Some times I'm getting recData null, when BackKey pressed.I should not get null beacuse the recdata i'm passing to next activity when user clicks on some button in this Activity?How to avoid null?

Answer (score 2):

In Activity3 you used an intent to launch Activity2. You did not put any extras in it. Therefore, when you get the bundle in Activity2

```
Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
```

It is actually null. You should do a checking before using it, like this:

```
Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
if(recdData != null) {
    actionArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("actionArray");
    comedyArray=recdData.getParcelableArrayList("comedyArray");
}
```

You should also know that using the current navigation, you will not have the `actionArray` and `comedyArray` as you expected when you launch Activity2 from Activity3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

You are getting getBaseContext() null

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this, Acivity2.class); //UPDATE HERE
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
                CategoryListView.this.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```